# Basic jQuery function wont work with external js file

Tags: jquery, html

I have been trying to get jQuery to work, and cant figure out what I am doing wrong. When I paste the code into the HTML doc between script tags, it runs fine, but when I try to use a separate script file, it doesn't work. I have a local copy of the jQuery file, and I have tried using a CDN as well.

**HTML**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="script/main.js"></script>
    <script src="script/jquery.js"></script>

    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Heading 1</h1>
        <h2>Heading 2</h2>

        <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
        <p>This is another paragraph.</p>

        <div>This is some important text!</div><br>

        <button>Add classes to elements</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
    .important {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: xx-large;
}

.blue {
    color: blue;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("button").click(function () {
        $("h1, h2, p").addClass("blue");
        $("div").addClass("important");
    });
});
```

Comment: your code is referencing `main.js` before `jquery.js`. jQuery needs to be loaded before you can use it.

Answer (score 1):

Switch these:

```
<script src="script/main.js"></script>
<script src="script/jquery.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="script/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="script/main.js"></script>
```

Also consider the use of a CDN:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
```